# Update new Date every function call

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have a function (called `metro`) that uses the current local time. I also have a `setInterval()` that calls this function every 30 seconds, but the `setInterval()` is returning always the same value, when my intention is that the time gets updated by the `new Date()`

```
let now = new Date()
let hourNow = now.getHours()
let minutesNow = now.getMinutes()
const interval = setInterval(metro, 30000, hourNow, minutesNow);
```

Comment: You can use new Date() within your metro function instead of passing the params via setInterval. Since you have declared the now variable once it will not be updated automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the times to change you'll need to create your date and the other variables inside the interval function.

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  let now = new Date()
  let hourNow = now.getHours()
  let minutesNow = now.getMinutes()
  metro(hourNow, minutesNow);
}, 30000);
```

Comment: i love you my man

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
let now , hourNow , minutesNow;

function metro(){
now = new Date()
hourNow = now.getHours()
minutesNow = now.getMinutes()
}

setInterval(metro , 30000)
```

declearing the vairables in the global scope will allow them to be updated when the function is called and accessed outside the function too.

**Key point**

declearing the `now = new Date()` inside the `metro` function will give you the new time every time the function is called by the `setInterval` function.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval()` function doesn't return the same return value from `metro()` function. It returns `intervalID` numeric value representing the interval created. You can check MDN for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#return_value

In order to update the date value each time `setInterval()` is triggered, you need to move the `new Date()` inside the `setInterval()` callback function:

```
const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const now = new Date();
    const hourNow = now.getHours();
    const minutesNow = now.getMinutes();

    metro(hourNow, minutesNow);
}, 30000);
```